# Japanese characters get Garbled on form post

Tags: c#, webforms

I have troubles getting Japanese characters to be handled correct. I have a webform that fetch data from a sql server and place that data in a table and corresponding textboxes, the user can the change the value in the textbox and save it to the database. If I fetch a Japanese text and don't change anything the update works as expected and the Japanese text is intact  and the same in the database. But if I change the value with a new Japanese word that I copied from google translate the updated text in the database become garbled characters. I can see that those garbled characters is there when I get the value before the actual update, so there is nothing wrong with the update statement (`ExecuteCommand($"UPDATE MYTESTTABLE Set MYNOTE = N'{row.MYNOTE}'  WHERE ID = '{row.ID}'");`)

In my Web.config file I have set `<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />`

Is there anything I can do besides what I have allready done to make the characters stay intact?

Comment: Please switch to using SQL parameters.

Comment: I don't understand, do you mean I should change the original query to fit the appropriate way of posting a question or do you mean there is something wrong with the SQL command (which it is not).

Comment: The issue at the moment is that it's vulnerable to SQL injection. The way the query is being built at the moment (without using parameters) might also contribute to it not being saved to the database correctly.

Comment: I'm focusing on trying to get the correct value inserted at this moment. The Japanese characters is garbled before I build the update statement and that was my issue and question.

Comment: Wait. So in `row.MYNOTE` it's garbled? Before the update statement gets executed? If I were you, I would remove any database aspect from your question and provide a [mcve] for the UI / code behind where you receive the string.

Comment: I found the solution, I needed to HttpUtility.HtmlEncode the japanese value before insert it into the database.